# Haskell Phonebook adding elements

Tags: function, haskell, insert

He guys,

My task is to program a phonebook in Haskell. Therefore type Phonebook is given. The Phonebook maps names(String) to their phone numbers(String). But now I have problems implementing the function 'insert':

Heres the code:

```
type Phonebook = String -> String

emptyPhonebook :: Phonebook
emptyPhonebook  = \_->""

insert :: String -> String -> Phonebook -> Phonebook
insert name number emptyPhonebook = (\name->number)     --is this correct?
insert name number existingPhonebook = ??
```

My question: How do I insert a function in a function? I mean now I have to insert an entry consisting of a function (name -> number) in another function (existing Phonebook) or am I wrong? Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: This exact question was asked yesterday already. Anyways, don't represent it using functions; that seems horribly convoluted. Use a Map (the structure, not the function).

Comment: SO you mean solving this with lists. Thats of course way easier but I have to solve it this way also :(

Comment: Not lists, a Map/Dictionary. They associate one input with another, which is what you're trying to do here: associate a name with a number.

Comment: And the first problem I see is that you have the type of phonebook as a function. If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, the phonebook itself shouldn't be a function, each entry is a function. `Phonebook` should be a list of functions.

Comment: So you mean type Phonebook = [String -> String] ?

Comment: Unfortunately the definition of Phonebook is given in the task and I have to solve it this way

Comment: Sorry, I can't help then. It doesn't make any sense. I'd ask your teacher to clarify that. It kind of makes sense for a Phonebook to be a list of functions (kind of), but I don't see how you could store multiple bits of data in a single function in any kind of sane way.

Comment: Yes thats the thing. Ill ask my teacher. Maybe the task is wrong :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Np, also, my Haskell is pretty rusty, but I'm pretty sure you can't pattern match on `emptyPhonebook` like you're doing; it's not a constructor.

Comment: @Carcigenicate correct you cannot pattern match. However, you can achieve the task with `String -> String`: start with `const ""` for the empty phone book, and `insert name number pb = \n -> if n == name then number else pb n`, but deletion will be tricky.

Comment: The funny part is that it was asked by "J. Doe", now this question is asked by "John Doe" :)

Comment: Thanks Zeta, is there any way to test it? Beacuse testing it with 'insert "name" "number" emptyPhonebook' gives the error 'No instance for (Show Phonebook) arising from a use of ‘print’
'

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
type Phonebook = String -> String

emptyPhonebook :: Phonebook
emptyPhonebook _ = ""

insert :: String -> String -> Phonebook -> Phonebook
insert name number phonebook = 
        case phonebook name of 
             "" -> (\s -> if s == name then number else phonebook s)
             _ -> phonebook
```

Comment: Ahh, just chaining the functions. I've done that in JS, can't believe I didn't think of it here.

Comment: Thanks Michail but I dont understand the variable s. You didnt initialize it so how can you compare it with the string name?

Comment: @JohnDoe `s` is going to be the argument of the resulting function, so when you call `nonEmptyPhonebook "John"` it'll be replaced with 'John'.

Comment: Okay I see. How can I test it? Testing with 'insert "John"' "12345" emptyPhonebook' gives the following error : 'No instance for (Show Phonebook) arising from a use of ‘print’
'

Comment: @JohnDoe You need to save the new phonebook into a variable and then call it with some arguments. Since a phonebook is actually a function you can't print it directly, but you can print its return value.

Comment: @Michail AH okay but how do I save a phonebook in a variable? With 'let n = newphonebook'?And why is 'insert "John"' "12345" emptyPhonebook' not working? Isnt the return value "12345" here? Sorry for the questions Im new to Haskell :)

Comment: @JohnDoe No, the return value of function `insert` is another function, which will return "12345" given the argument "John" (and something else for different arguments if it's not the first time you use `insert`). In interactive session `n = insert ...` should suffice.