# Haskell create a Phonebook as a list of tuples

Tags: list, function, haskell, search, tuples

I need to create a phonebook as a list of tuples:

```
type Phonebook :: [(String,String)]
```

As you can see in the code, the first element should represent the name and the second element the number. So the result of

```
Main> phonebookone = insert "Dad" "90213" (insert "mum" "8912" emptyPhonebook)
Main> phonebookone
```

should be `[("Dad","90213"),("mum","8912")]` but I only get `[("Dad","90213")]`

My code:

```
emptyPhonebook :: Phonebook
emptyPhonebook = [("","")]

insert :: String -> String -> Phonebook -> Phonebook
insert name number phonebook = [(name,number)]
```

Also i need to create a function `search`, which search for numbers or better if the first element of a tuple exists in the list and is the same like the String, who you search for, it will result the second element of the tuple.

So it should be:

```
Main> search "Dad" phonebook
"90213"
```

My unfinished code for this:

```
search :: String -> Phonebook -> String
search name phonebook = if ..???
```

Comment: As it is, your `insert` just discards existing entries. You are looking for `(name, number) : phonebook` rather than just `[(name, number)]`

Comment: Your `emptPhonebook` actually has an entry.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you are already the third one asking for related questions. See for instance [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41696230/haskell-phonebook-adding-elements?s=1|0.0000).

Comment: thanks Michail! your solution solves the main Problem. But now the result is [("Dad","90213"),("mum","8912"),("","")] insted of                                [("Dad","90213"),("mum","8912")]. Do you know a better solution for emptyPhonebook?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem My question is a Little bit different, because i'm tring to create a "Phonebook" as a list of tuples and the other guy as a function. I can't derive or use this way of thinking for my Programm.

Comment: @J.Dean: yeah but you had a "J. Doe" and a "John Doe" (although I currently fail to find his/her question) who implemented it as a list of tuples as well. Now there is a "J.Dean" , so I expect the next one to be "John Dean" :).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell Phonebook adding elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41696230/haskell-phonebook-adding-elements)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem haha i've needed a quick name to ask my question and i saw the question of John Doe before, so i think i got inspired. By the way do you know a way to implement a function, which checks whether a string starts with certain chars. I Need this function as an extension for my phonebook :D

Comment: @J.Dean: Without wanting to be rude, I think it is SO's policy to ask different questions for - well - different questions such that people can easily find them :)

Answer (score 2):

A lot of things are wrong with your code:

- Your `emptyPhonebook` actually is not empty: indeed you have defined one tuple in it: the one with an empty string as both the name and the phone number. You can correct this to:

  ```
  emptyPhonebook :: Phonebook
  emptyPhonebook = []
  ```
- Your insertion method `insert` actually creates a `Phonebook` with one entry: the one you want to add, the remainder of the phonebook is ignored. You can use the CONS (`(:)`) function for this:

  ```
  insert :: String -> String -> Phonebook -> Phonebook
  insert name number = (:) (name,number)
  ```

Now to answer the main question. First of all, most Haskell programmers consider `if` to be rather *un*-Haskell: in Haskell one uses *pattern matching* and *guards* to set constraints on rules.

Since your search is probably supposed to error when it does not find a person with that name (you did not specify this), there are actually two code paths we have to consider:

- the one where we are given a non-empty list where the first element matches our search: in that case we return the corresponding number; and
- the one where the name does not match in which case we simply continue our search in th tail of the given list.

These rules in Haskell look like:

```
search query ((name,number):other) = ...
```

Now in case `query` and `name` match, we thus should return the number so:

```
search query ((name,number):other) | query == name = number
```

In the other case, we recursively continue our noble quest:

```
search query ((name,number):other) | otherwise = search query other
```

So putting it together, you get:

```
search :: String -> Phonebook -> String
search query ((name,number):other) | query == name = number
                                   | otherwise = search query other
```

This will return the number given it is in the phonebook, and otherwise error.

**EDIT**:

Given you want to return `"error"` (as a string) when the search fails, you only have to add an additional rule:

```
search _ [] = "error"
```

So putting it all together gives:

```
search :: String -> Phonebook -> String
search query ((name,number):other) | query == name = number
                                   | otherwise = search query other
search _     [] = "error"
```

Comment: is there a possibility to avoid the error and  instead of this return a string ?

Comment: @J.Dean: what should the string look like?

Comment: @J.Dean: but you don't have any number in that case: the program errors if it cannot find the number.

Comment: I mean something like | query == name = number | search query other == name = number | otherwise "error". In this wrong Code it only search the first entry. I Need the correct Version of this, where the programm search in all tuples in the list. thanks for the fast answers!

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned your insert function is incomplete, otherwise no matter what you try to insert to it it'll only have 1 record, so if you try to search for a specific contact in your phonebook it'll only retrieve the only 1. But I won't answer that as that has already been answered.

Then just apply simple recursion over your phonebook

```
search :: String -> Phonebook -> String
search name ((contactName, contactNumber):phonebook) = if contactName == name then contactNumber else search name phonebook
```

or you can use filter

```
search :: String -> Phonebook -> String
search name phonebook = snd . head . filter ((==name) . fst) $ phonebook
```

The only problem with the second option that it will retrieve the first contact with the same name and it might not be the one we're querying for, a solution to this would be to use `Either String phonebook` as the return type if there is more than one individual with the same name, so this:

```
search :: String -> Phonebook -> Either String phonebook
search name phonebook = let getContacts nm contacts = filter ((==nm) . fst) $ contacts
                    in case (length $ getContacts name phonebook) == 1 of
                             True -> Left $ snd . head . getContacts name $ phonebook
                             False -> Right $ (getContacts name) $ phonebook
```

Ignore the last one, is untested and I don't think is exactly what you want, I just added this just in case as extra.